# php 5.2 + mysql 5.1 character encoding issue

Tags: php, character-encoding

Background:
There is a table, events; this table is formatted latin1.  Individual columns in this table are set to utf8.  The column we will cherry pick to discuss is 'title' which is one of the utf8 columns. The website is set for utf8 both via apache and the meta tag.

As a test, if I save `décor or ©` into the title field and perform

```
select title, LENGTH(title) as len, CHAR_LENGTH(title) as chlen 
from events where length(title) != char_length(title)
```

I will get `décor or ©, 12, 10` back as a result; which is expected showing that the data has indeed been properly saved into my utf8 column.

However, upon echoing the title out to a page, it's mangeld into `d�cor or �` which makes no sense to me since, as mentioned before, the character encoding is set to utf-8 on the page.

Not sure if this final detail makes a difference but if I edit the page and resubmit the mangled text it turns into `d%uFFFDcor or %uFFFD` both in the database and when displayed to the page.  Further submits cause no change.

Actual Question:
Does anyone have an idea as to what I may be doing wrong? :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's likely one of three problems.

**1. Mysql's connection is not using UTF-8**

This means that it's converted to another charset (likely Latin-1) before it hits PHP.  I've found the best solution is to run the following queries:

```
SET CHARACTER SET = "utf8";
SET character_set_database = "utf8";
SET character_set_connection = "utf8";
SET character_set_server = "utf8";
```

<strike>**2. The page rendered is not really set to UTF-8**</strike>

Set both the `Content-type` header and the `<meta>` tag content types to UTF-8.  Some browsers don't respect one or the other...

```
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
```

As noted in the comments, that's not the problem...

**3. You're doing something to the string before echoing it**

Most of PHP's string functions will not do well with UTF-8.  If you're calling a normal function that doesn't accept a `$charset` parameter, the chances are that it won't work with utf-8 strings (such as `str_replace`).  If it does have a `$charset` parameter (like [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), make sure that you set it.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Can't be 2, otherwise there'd be 2 off characters instead of 1 replacement character.

Comment: I've tried running the provided queries in my bootstrap process right after opening the db connection;  the results of saving to the database now are: 'd?cor or ?' and I've var_dump'd the results coming from the db before anything else could be executed and there is no difference.  Thanks for the help so far. :)

Comment: That actually implies that it's getting converted to Latin-1 at some point.  Do you have output buffering enabled?  Are you sure you sent the proper headers?  To see if the characters are correct when the come out of the db, run this on it: `function dec($str) { for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) { echo dechex(ord($str[$i])); }`.  it'll give you the hex values (and you can see if anything is mucking with the output before you echo it)...

Comment: I've tracked it down to something inside Smarty mangling it; the data is perfect before and after smarty display if I output directly from the original datastructure but what smarty itself outputs is mangled.  I'm sitting in the smarty irc channel now hoping someone there may have any ideas.  Again, thanks for all the help so far :)

Comment: Well, then it looks like #3 was the correct answer ;-)...  Good luck tracking it down (I can't stand smarty, so sorry I can't help much there)...

Comment: I understand, I can't stand it either; was a decision made before my time.  It's actually being phased out as things are redesigned;  I may just convert the three views that exhibit this problem into phtml files and move on for now.  Thanks for all the help, I'll mark your answer as correct due to #3.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you track it down!

Comment: Hmm, going to ask in case you just happen to still monitor this, but do you have any clue why ob_start() would cause the mangling?  Turns out when Zend_View::render() is caled it does ob_start(); if I comment the ob_start() out then no mangling of the data.  Obviously that's not the optimal solution so..

Comment: The data is not being output buffered?  Without seeing the code, I can't really tell...  But look for an ob_get_clean() or ob_get_contents() call...